# Pause/resume animation when app is in background/foreground

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have a SwiftUI app in which there's a cloud that slowly moves across the screen, then resets to its starting position and begins the animation again, infinitely.

I accomplish this with the following code:

```
import SwiftUI

struct Clouds {
    @State private var xOffset: CGFloat = 0.0
    @State private var yOffset: CGFloat = 0.0

    var body: some View {
        Image("cloud") 
           .resizable()
           .scaledToFit()
           .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
           .frame(height: 200.0)
           .offset(x: xOffset, y: yOffset)
           .onAppear {
               DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.1) {
                   yOffset = MainData.screenHeight * CGFloat.random(in: 0...1)
                   
                   withAnimation(Animation.linear(duration: 80).repeatForever(autoreverses: false)){
                       xOffset = MainData.screenWidth
                   }
               }
          }
    }
}
```

**Desired behavior:** When the app is sent to the background, the cloud should stop moving -- and when the app is brought to the foreground, the cloud should resume its movement *from where it left off*.

**Actual behavior:** When the app is sent to the background, *the cloud continues to animate*. The animation is completed, then *the cloud stays in its starting position* until the app is brought to the foreground.

**Question:** How can I make it so that the animation pauses when the app is sent to the background, and resumes when the app is brought to the foreground?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround, I decided to render the clouds via SpriteKit instead of SwiftUI. SpriteKit has the desired behavior by default: the clouds stop animating when the app is brought out of the foreground and begin animating from the same position when the app is brought back into the foreground.

It'd be cool if someone else could answer the original question for SwiftUI, though -- so I won't accept my own answer.